# Oracle SQL - number of WITH clause column names does not match number of elements in select list

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have the following:

```
WITH Course_Skill(c_code, skillcode) AS (
  SELECT c_code, skillcode
  FROM course NATURAL JOIN taughtin),
CourseSet_Skill(csetID, skillcode) AS (
  SELECT csetID, skillcode
    FROM CourseSet CSet
    JOIN Course_Skill CS ON CSet.c_code1=CS.c_code
 UNION
  SELECT csetID, skillcode
    FROM CourseSet CSet
    JOIN Course_Skill CS ON CSet.c_code2=CS.c_code
 UNION
  SELECT csetID, skillcode
    FROM CourseSet CSet
    JOIN Course_Skill CS ON CSet.c_code3=CS.c_code
),
/* more stuff */
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-32038: number of WITH clause column names does not match number of elements in select list
```

Can anyone explain why this error occurs? The location of the error is stated as occurring in the first `FROM` clause after the `CourseSet_Skill` `WITH` clause.  `CourseSet_Skill` is defined as having 2 columns `(csetID & skillcode)` and the select statements also only consist of 2 columns, which is the same amount.

## UPDATE

The error was being caused by statement elsewhere in the
query.  The error code just located it to this section of the query
for some reason.  All is fixed and thank you all for your feedback.

Comment: what are you trying to do?its not how with clause should be use

Comment: Can you put a small example up on Sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: From the last comma - just before /* more stuff /* I assume that more named sub queries exists - apart from the ones shown?

Comment: @JensKrogsboell is right. Are you sure the error is in the clauses you showed us?

Comment: @JensKrogsboell I think your(deleted now) answer is ok.

Comment: So what is hidden behind  `/* more stuff */`?

Comment: @FlorinGhita I have undeleted it - only I realized that Paddyngton seems to know already. And also - answers should not "assume":-)

Comment: Yes, but... until the user do not add some details, that would be the answer. In my opinion, of course.

Comment: @Paddyngton Please update the question with the wrong code, otherwise the question would not be useful for other readers of stackoverlow. The solution, if it is not the ensKrogsboell's answer should be put in an answer from your side(it's legal and recommended)

Answer (score 2):

When you have

```
with q(a,b) as (select x, y from ...
```

a and b provides aliases for x and y.

I must assume that one of your with clauses are like:

```
with q(a,b) as ( select x from ...
```

or

```
with q(a,b) as ( select x, y, z from...
```

such that the number of colums actually selected do not match the number of aliases.